# Git - zip added/modified files since commit id

Tags: git, archive, git-diff

I try to list the differences between a specific commit id (in specific branch) and the last one and to compress them by keeping the tree

e.g - output.zip content :

```
+---newFolder01
|   +---newFile02
|   +---newFile03
+---existingFolder04
|   +---existingFolder05
|       +---alteredFile06
+---newFile07
+---alteredFile08
```

I have access to the gitlab repository of my project, if it can simplify the command..

Optionally, i want to add a file in the zip archive that indicate which files have been deleted.

I saw that git-diff must be used for what a want, but, i don't know if it takes into account all intermediate commit differences? And how to combine it with a zip command ?

Comment: So you want a complete archive of your working tree at some point in time, and a diff describing additions, changes and deletions between that point in time and some other (future? past?) commit. Why not just redirect the output of `git diff` to a patch file in the tree, and include it when you zip up?

Comment: Yes, from a specific past commit to the last one, i don't want to includes unmodified files in the archives. What do you mean by "patch file" ? i'm beginner in git system

Comment: I think maybe the real question is, what do you plan to *do* with this archive? Because it's a very unusual thing to want, and it may be that git provides better support for a different way to do whatever you're trying to do...

Comment: I have applications on mobile devices (ios, uwp), I use git to update app datas, theses datas are différents by costumers i've. So I have one branch by customer and I want each devices to check and download modification since theirs lasts "commit update" on connection with server.